# Queue running infinitely but doen't have access to server [Laravel 6.X]

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have an issue with jobs in Laravel 6.X
My jobs queues are in `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`.
Problem : I have a running job and it doesn't stop/fail. So i'm here to ask you if I can stop him without access to server (so I can't use CLI). I have access to database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try delete the job record from jobs table if you can't use the CLI.

Comment: I will try this :)

Comment: Not work. I will wait my mate to restart. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Laravel Horizon https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon good tool to manage laravel jobs

Comment: I can't install this at the moment but thank you for this solution. This will be helpful for another project :)